# Audio Not Playing in HTML

Tags: html, html5-audio

The audio player shows up but the audio won't play.
The audio file is in the same folder as the HTML file...

```
<audio controls>
            <source src="audioFileName.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            Audio element not supported by your browser.
</audio>
```

What's wrong with the code?
I've tried mp3 as well with no luck.

Comment: I have tried `mp3` and it's working. Maybe you are giving wrong audio url

Comment: What would be the right format for the audio url? I thought that as long as the audio and HTML files were in the same folder, that I'd just have to write the audio file name...

Comment: Add the screenshots of your folder and where the audio file and index file you have placed. Add screenshots in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also tried it with an mp3 audio file (same folder as well) and the code works, so most likely the problem is with the audio file itself. Maybe your navigator doesn't support it, or the name of the file is slightly wrong.

Comment: I checked the name of the file and it's correct :-( How would I check to see if the audio file has an issue? The file's playing fine when I click on it...

Comment: Try the same code with a different audio. Also check for your navigator compatibility with the audio format.